# Difference between "alert(a)'' and ''alert(a);var a =1;'' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(a);
</script>
```

Console log shows : "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined";

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(a);
    var a = 1;
</script>
```

at the middle of the browse, Log shows: "undefined"

How does this code run in js and what causes this difference

Comment: [Variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: in second case `var a = 1;` if you will declare variable after alert  `undefined` error will occurs

Comment: there is a typo it should be alert(a) not alter(a)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(a);
    var a = 1;
</script>
```

`var a ;` is hoisted to the top and it becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a;
    alert(a);
    a = 1;
</script>
```

so by the time `a` was alerted, it was `undefined`

In this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(a);
</script>
```

a was not defined at all, so it gave an error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"`